# how can I get the return value of a program executed by exec?

Tags: c, exec, return-value

I have this c code:

```
if(fork()==0){
  execl("/usr/bin/fsck", "fsck", "/dev/c0d0p1s0", NULL);
}
```

it calls `execl` to run `fsck` for checking the filesystem `/dev/c0d0p1s0`.

My question is: how can I get the return value of `fsck`?

I need the return value of `fsck` to check whether the file system is consistence or not.

Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have the parent process wait for the child to exit:

```
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == -1) {
  // error, no child created
}
else if (pid == 0) {
  // child
}
else {
  // parent
  int status;
  if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) == -1) {
    // handle error
  }
  else {
    // child exit code in status
    // use WIFEXITED, WEXITSTATUS, etc. on status
  }
}
```

Comment: Yup, guess I misread it! I was trying to point out; return code would be set in "errno". Well off course to read that return code parent has to wait for the child :) ... Anyways deleted the answer.

Comment: @Roger thank you. I will try it out and let you know what was the result.

Comment: It must be noted that in the particular case of calling `execl()` in the child, you should also call `_exit()` right after that to prevent the child from continuing execution in case `execl()` fails. You should also have a new case in the parent that handles an eventual `execl()` failure.

Comment: @Blagovest: Didn't you already mention that in your answer?

Comment: @Roger Pate and @Blagovest: Thank you guys for your help, really appriciate it

Answer (score 7):

You must call `wait()` or `waitpid()` in the parent process and it will give you the exit status of the program executed by `execl()`. Not calling one of these will make the child process remain a zombie when it terminates, i.e. a process that is dead but stays in the process table because its parent wasn't interested in its return code.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

...

pid_t pid;
int status;

if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
  /* the child process */
  execl(..., NULL);
  /* if execl() was successful, this won't be reached */
  _exit(127);
}

if (pid > 0) {
  /* the parent process calls waitpid() on the child */
  if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) > 0) {
    if (WIFEXITED(status) && !WEXITSTATUS(status)) {
      /* the program terminated normally and executed successfully */
    } else if (WIFEXITED(status) && WEXITSTATUS(status)) {
      if (WEXITSTATUS(status) == 127) {
        /* execl() failed */
      } else {
        /* the program terminated normally, but returned a non-zero status */
        switch (WEXITSTATUS(status)) {
          /* handle each particular return code that the program can return */
        }
      }
    } else {
      /* the program didn't terminate normally */
    }
  } else {
    /* waitpid() failed */
  }
} else {
  /* failed to fork() */
}
```

The `_exit()` call in the child is to prevent it from continuing execution in case `execl()` fails. Its return status (127) is also necessary to distinguish the case of an eventual `execl()` failure in the parent.